# New operator using char in C++

Tags: c++, char

Why this code doesnt work? It throws runtime error without compiler errors or warnings.

```
 int main(void) {

    char *korisnik = new char[20];
    korisnik = "Bizuterija";
    *(korisnik+1) = 'h'; // error here!
    cout << korisnik << endl;

    delete[] korisnik;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And that's why you use std::string in C++

Comment: In C++, you shouldn't assign the address of string literals to char *, and instead to const char *. It is allowed only for backwards-compatibility with C.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
korisnik = "Bizuterija";
```

This line replaces the address stored in `korisnik` and allocated by `new` with an address in data segment of the executable which you can't modify, since it's a string literal. You actually create a memory leak here.

Try by copying the content of the string to the pointed memory instead:

```
strncpy(korisnik, "Bizuterija", 20);
```

By the way, since you work with C++, you should definitely use `std::string`.

Comment: I was editing the answer while you posted your comment. I just realized it was tagged as C++ later (even if `cout` was a hint)

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest switching to std::string since you're using c++.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string korisnik = "Bizuterija";
    korisnik[1] = 'h';
    std::cout <<korisnik <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```